# Spring boot mongodb substring in string or index of

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have spring boot with mongodb collection called `bad_words` and it looks like this

```
@Document(collection ="bad_words")
@Data
public class BadWord {

   @Id
   private String word;
}
```

Now I want to search if _id is part of provided bad word.

If I try this

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").regex(".*shit.*", "i"));
BadWord badWord = mongoOperations.findOne(query, BadWord.class);
```

I get match found, but if I try this

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").regex(".*shit1234.*", "i"));
BadWord badWord = mongoOperations.findOne(query, BadWord.class);
```

No match found. How can I reverse check if _id is substring or full match of provided word.

My aim to to find if word contains bad words in id and replace bad word's character with character `*`.

Here are some examples of doc

```
{
 "_id": "badword1",
 "_class": "com.example.models.BadWord"
},
{
 "_id": "badword2",
 "_class": "com.example.models.BadWord"
}
```

And words I want to filter

- badword1
- badword1badword2
- badword123

Any help?

Comment: I'm not clear on why you are appending the `1234` characters to your search string. Is this to reduce the number of searches that you are making?

Comment: so that is variable, it can be anything, I added  for example. It is user input of bad word. i want to find if substring of provided bad word is in id.

Comment: Right but doesn't your first query accomplish that? Your first query will (correctly) flag _more_ potential documents than the sconed one right?

Comment: No, it is not working. For the first query if id and input values are in the format ("_id", "input") ex:  ("badword", "badword") or ("badword123", "badword") it will work.  but if I have  ("badword", "badwordanotherbadword") it will not.

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that you are looking to find documents whose (user generated) `_id` contains one or more words (or phrases) from a pre-defined list. I don't think that doing a "reverse check" where you provide all of the words in a concatenated string for a regex search is the way to go.

Instead, how about using `$in`? Consider the list of words that you want to identify are the strings `"one"`, `"two"`, and `"three"`. Instead, how about using [the `$in` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) passing it a list of regex searches (one for each of the words to identify)? The query might look like this:

```
db.foo.find({_id:{$in:[/one/i,/two/i,/three/i]}})
```

Two limitations (one in MongoDB and one in mongoplayground) prevent me from demonstrating with a playground example directly. Consider the following documents in the collection:

```
test> db.foo.find()
[
  { _id: 'one' },
  { _id: 'between one another' },
  { _id: 'two' },
  { _id: 'two three' },
  { _id: 'two and three' },
  { _id: 'four' },
  { _id: 'five' },
  { _id: 'word' },
  { _id: 'normal' },
  { _id: 'normal word' }
]
```

The query successfully identifies the five offending documents:

```
test> db.foo.find({_id:{$in:[/one/i,/two/i,/three/i]}})
[
  { _id: 'between one another' },
  { _id: 'one' },
  { _id: 'two' },
  { _id: 'two and three' },
  { _id: 'two three' }
]
```

Comment: hey thanks for posting. but I am not sure if this will work. I have single word. Even if i do. db.foo.find({_id:{$in:['one'}}), that is not solving the problem. I am not sure if I explained question wrong.

Comment: are you able to get result where id is one and input (word in list) is "onetwo"

Comment: You're using the exact string match syntax in the comment above which will _not_ work. It needs to be regex operators that get added to the `$in` list. Can you update your question with some sample documents, sample values, and note which documents should match and which shouldn't?

Comment: This is the main question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thanks! If the second document (`{ "_id": "badword2" }`) is supposed to match, why is the second entry in the filter list `badword1badword2` instead of `badword2`?