# spring boot mongodb Aggregation indexOfCP

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to write this query using spring boot, as you can see I have switched default "John" as first parameter and $username as second.

```
db.user.aggregate(
[
 {
   $addFields:
      {
        searchIndex: { $indexOfCP: ["John" ,"$username"]},
      }
  },

  { 
    $match: {

         searchIndex: {$ne: -1}

       }
    },
 ]
)
```

I have tried this

```
    AddFieldsOperation maximMatchedWords =
            AddFieldsOperation
                    .builder()
                    .build()
                    .addField("searchIndex", StringOperators.valueOf("John").indexOfCP("$username"));

    MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("searchIndex").ne(-1));
   Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(maximMatchedWords, match);

    AggregationResults<User> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, "users", User.class);
```

but it doesnt works and always return all results.

Comment: Perhaps this is a silly or irrelevant question, but is there a particular reason that you are _searching_ the data this way? This approach will require a full collection scan to convert the `username` field from every document each time it is executed. Perhaps you could identify your result set first and then calculate the `searchIndex` value afterwards from just the relevant documents if it is needed?

Comment: @user20042973 thanks for comment. yes I am searching this way for specific reason. please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74526613/spring-boot-mongodb-substring-in-string-or-index-of